# Trying to unmarshal struct that has a slice of interfaces gives me "cannot unmarshal object into go struct" error

Tags: go, struct, interface

so I've searched stackoverflow and haven't quite found someone with an error like mine. In short, I have a struct that has an array of interfaces. When I marshal it, I have no issues. When I try to unmarshal it, I receive a "cannot unmarshal object into go struct" error. Here's a minimal example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Animal interface {
    MakeSound(string)
}

type Dog struct {
    Name string
}

func (d Dog) MakeSound(sound string) {
    fmt.Printf("%s sound goes %s\n", d.Name, sound)
}

type Cat struct {
    Name string
}

func (c Cat) MakeSound(sound string) {
    fmt.Printf("%s sound goes %s\n", c.Name, sound)
}

type Zoo struct {
    Name string
    Animals []Animal
}

func main() {
    myZoo := Zoo {
        Name: "Tim's Zoo",
        Animals: []Animal{
                Cat{
                    Name: "Tabby",
                },
            },
        }
    
    var newZoo Zoo
    
    b, err := json.Marshal(myZoo)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("marshal error: %s", err)
    }
    
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &newZoo); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unmarshal error: %s", err)
    }
    
    fmt.Printf("New Zoo: %v\n", newZoo)
}
```

You can run it for yourself here:

https://play.golang.org/p/8wUZQh0zEKR

I can get around this by changing the Zoo struct to just include a cat struct, but it seems to negate the benefits of using an interface. Any idea how I should solve this? Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: `Animal` is an interface. When you marshal it, it holds values of concrete types which can be marshaled. The concrete type info is not transferred into JSON. When you unmarshal, the `encoding/json` package cannot guess what type it should use, so unmarshaling fails. You have to transfer the type info into JSON and use a custom unmarshaler which uses that info to unmarshal into the proper type.

Comment: Taking a step back, what would you expect the generated JSON to look like? How would you, a human, tell whether a particular item with only a `Name` attribute was a `Dog` or `Cat` or something else? Generally, you would do this by including type information along with each item: `{"Animals": [{"type": "cat", "name": "Tabby"}, {"type": "dog", "name": "snoopy"}]}`, etc. You could think about rewriting your code around this sort of structure.

Comment: It depends on what the JSON could look like. If you expect all `Animal`s to appear in JSON, that's literally not possible. You can't expect to handle all Go types that implement `Animal`, any future type may do so that are not yet known.

Comment: larsks, I'll try to rewrite my code based on your suggestion. Thanks.